# Why won't cout << work with overloaded * operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm creating my first class, mainly guided by Overland's C++ Without Fear. I've made the overloaded friend ostream operator<<, which works fine. I've also overloaded the * operator, and that works fine. What doesn't work is when I try to output the result of the * operator directly:

```
BCD bcd(10);  //bcd is initialised to 10
BCD bcd2(15); //bcd2 is initialised to 15
cout << bcd;  //prints 10
bcd2 = bcd2 * 2; //multiplies bcd2 by 2
cout << bcd2; //prints 30

cout << bcd * 2 //SHOULD print 20, but compiler says
//main.cpp:49: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << BCD::operator*(int)(2)'
```

For info, here are my prototypes:

```
BCD operator*(int z);
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, BCD &bcd);
```

As far as I can tell, operator* returns a BCD, so operator<< should be able to print it. Help please!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What's happening is that `bcd * 2` is generating a temporary `BCD`, which cannot bind to a `BCD &`.  Try replacing the `<<` operator with one of these:

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const BCD &bcd);
```

or

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, BCD bcd);
```

or even

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const BCD bcd);
```

The first one works, since binding a temporary variable to a constant reference is explicity allowed, unlike binding to a non-const reference.  The other ones work by making a copy of the temporary variable.

Edit:
As noted in the comments - prefer the const & version in most cases, since modifying an object in a streaming operator will be surprising to anyone using your class.  Getting this to compile may require adding `const` declarations to your classes member function where appropriate.

Comment: I'd prefer the const variant, since -- obviously -- a << should never modify the parameter.

Comment: Good point - it's always best to stick with what is expected from an operator and modifying an object in operator<< would be a suprise indeed.

Comment: Josh - you are a god among men! Before your edit about the const declarations I was having problems - but that fixed it! Many many thanks.