# Error when using overloaded operator << with operator *

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've recently tried operator overloading, and have looked at this stackoverflow page (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) about operator overloading.

I have overloaded the * operator and can run code such as

```
Vector2 a(2, 3);
Vector2 b(5, 8);
Vector2 c = a*b;
```

but get the compile time error `error: invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >' and 'Vector2')`

When running code such as

```
std::cout << a*b;
```

Here is Vector2.cpp

```
#include "Vector2.h"

Vector2::Vector2(const float x, const float y) {
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

Vector2 &Vector2::operator*=(const Vector2 &rhs) {
    this->x *= rhs.x;
    this->y *= rhs.y;
    return *this;
}

std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &out, Vector2 &vector) {
    return out << "(" << vector.x << ", " << vector.y << ")";
}
```

and here is Vector2.h

```
#include <iostream>

class Vector2 {
    public:
        float x;
        float y;

        Vector2(const float x, const float y);
        Vector2 &operator*=(const Vector2 &rhs);
};

inline Vector2 operator*(Vector2 lhs, const Vector2 &rhs) {
    lhs *= rhs;
    return lhs;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Vector2 &vector);
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: have you checked using parentheses: `cout << (a*b)`?

Comment: Yes that was the first thing I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: Here's the proof why not: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't cout << work with overloaded * operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451983/why-wont-cout-work-with-overloaded-operator)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that

```
a*b
```

returns a temporary, so you need:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Vector2 &vector);
//                                            |
//                                      notice const
```

as a temporary can't bind to a non-const reference.

Comment: To your second point, why?  The way he has it is perfect.  You've got to make a copy of the object anyway, so why not do it in the parameter list?

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley why make a copy to the object?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Can you write the function without making a copy?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I don't understand how you could write the function without making a copy. It's much easier to take a copy.

Comment: Ah yes you're both right. :) Dismiss that last part. @BenjaminLindley

Comment: As a bonus, this form allows you to take advantage of copy elision and move semantics if the first argument happens to be an r-value.  For full benefits, you would need to make another version which takes the rhs by value and the lhs by const ref.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
Vector2 c = a*b;
std::cout << c;
```

Comment: Yes that does work. What I am trying to do is to do std::cout << a*b;

Comment: Then you should update the operator signature to take const argument as others suggested.